# ¿Cómo enviar onclicklistener a un listView?

Tags: android, listview, customadapter, onclicklistener

Desconozco si es la mejor forma o hay otra vía pero necesito que a la hora de construir el listview, que sea cliqueable y cargue otra Actividad (cada item una Actividad diferente).

Clase principal:

```
    public class Inicio extends Activity {

    ListView lista;
    TextView textTitNivel, textNivel, textSabiduria, textExp;
    ProgressBar progressBarSabiduria, progressExp;
    View divider;

    static final String Operaciones[][] =
    {
                  { "Sumas I", "80","5" },
                  { "Restas I","110","2" },
                  { "Números I","50","7" }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

        lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        CustomAdapter adaptador = new CustomAdapter(this, Operaciones);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

        Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, "Test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, "Test3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                switch(position) {
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, "Case1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, SumasActivity.class);
                        //i.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(Inicio.this, SumasActivity.class);
                        //i.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
                        startActivity(i2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent i3 = new Intent(Inicio.this, SumasActivity.class);
                        //i.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
                        startActivity(i3);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Dentro del CustomAdapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView  textSabiduria = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textSabiduria);
        TextView textOp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textOp);
        TextView textExp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textExp);

        textOp.setText(Operaciones[i][0]);
        textExp.setText(Operaciones[i][1]);
        textSabiduria.setText(Operaciones[i][2]);

        return view;
    }
```

¿Donde coloco los siguientes onclicklistener? Estoy perdido..

Para el item "Sumas I":

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Sumas.class);
  startActivity(i);
```

Para el item "Restas I":

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Restas.class);
  startActivity(i);
```

Comment: en custom adapter puedes definir el onClickListener desde el layout que contega todos los elementos o desde algun boton q tenga tu vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues es sencillo la verdad. El evento `OnItemClick` lo implementas desde donde estas implementando el ListView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    CustomAdapter adaptador = new CustomAdapter(this, Operaciones);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    // Implementas la interfaz que se ejecutara al ser presionado un item
    // del ListView.
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Con switch evalúas la posición del item seleccionado y dependiendo
            // de la posicion seleccionada lanzas la actividad. 
            switch(position) {

                case 1:
                    // Lanzas la actividad 1
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Lanzas la actividad 2
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // Lanzas la actividad 3
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

Te recomiendo que leer los siguientes artículos para entender mejor como funcionan los ListView y las interfaces.

- [ListView (Documentación oficial)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html?hl=es-419)
- [Interface Java (Documentación oficial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)
- [Interfaz OnItemClickListener (esta es la interfaz que implementan los ListView para escuchar los item seleccionados)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)
- [Un tutorial muy completo sobre ListView (Hermosa Programación)](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/)

---

Otra cosa, para rellenar el ListView te recomiendo que utilices una lista de objetos en vez de un array bidimencional, te aseguro que es mas sencillo de entender y de mantener; en el tutorial de [Hermosa programación](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/) muestran como.

---

## Actualización

Si utilizas un botón o un ImageButton en los item de tu ListView, debes agregar al layout del item la propiedad: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`. Esto es para que el botón o el ImageButton no se roben el foco del item, cuando estos roban el foco del item, el item no puede ser clickeado.

Para mas información consulta:

[ListView OnItemClickListener no responde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)

[Focus problems with list rows and ImageButtons](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/08/focus-problems-with-list-rows-and.html)

---

Te recomiendo utilizar [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html), es un widget mas flexible que ListView para crear listas, y con el no tendrás estas clases de problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias David pero no me termina de funcionar. He actualziado el código en el primer mensaje. La lista se muestra bien pero no hace click ni pasa a la siguiente actividad. ¿Que ocurre?

Comment: Para estar seguro de que el evento `onItemClick` esta funcionando coloca un Toast dentro de el y me dejas saber. Los toast se crean de la siguiente manera: `Toast.makeText(this, "Hola mundo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`.

Comment: Para que no me de error lo he escrito de la siguiente forma: Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, "Hola mundo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); y no muestra ningún mensaje. Parece que no entra, lo he puesto dentro del onItemClick, encima del switch

Comment: Es un poco raro, no veo errores en el codigo. Por casualidad tendrias tu proyecto en GitHub.

Comment: No sabría subirlo a GitHub :S

Comment: He puesto un Toast antes del onItemClick y otro al finalizar y si los muestra, pero el que pongo dentro no.

Comment: Tiene que ser dentro de los **case**. Y asegúrate de presionar uno de los tres primeros item. Me dejas saber.

Comment: He puesto Toast en los cases y pulsando cualquier item de los 3 primeros no muestra nada

Comment: Ten en cuenta que donde tu me aconsejas "new OnItemClickListener()" yo he tenido que poner "new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()" porque me salia error y tenia que importar eso. No se si puede influir en algo.

Comment: Puedes actualizar el codigo.

Comment: Esta conversación se esta extendiendo demasiado. Continuemosla desde sala de chat [Conversación entre David Minaya y Antonio Ruiz](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76034/conversacion-entre-david-minaya-y-antonio-ruiz)

Comment: Ya lo he actualizado, el toast "test 2" se muestra pero el toast "test 3" y el "case 1" no.

Comment: Continuemos la conversación desde esta sala de chat [Conversación entre David Minaya y Antonio Ruiz](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76034/conversacion-entre-david-minaya-y-antonio-ruiz)

Comment: Me dice que necesito 20 de reputación para contestarte por chat.

Comment: Ok, entra este [enlace](https://codeshare.io/5Xp8Bo) y pega tu código en el.

Comment: Para que te muestre el Toast tendrás que llamar al contexto así: -`Inicio.this` ya que te encuentras dentro de una clase anónima

Comment: Sí, así es como lo hago pero no consigo que ese onClick se ejecute.